# Is it true that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=\mathbb{Z}_{p}\cap \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I know $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\subset \mathbb{Z}_{p}\cap \mathbb{Q}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at prime ideal $(p)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of p-adic integers. I wonder if the converse inclusion holds. I prefer an explanation where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is thought as the inverse limit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}$, namely at those prime numbers which become invertible. Here $p$ is the only exception. QED

Answer (score 3):

An element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a sequence $\{r_k+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ where the $r_k$'s are integers with $r_j\equiv r_k\mod p^k$ if $j>k$ and we have an inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p$ given by $r\rightarrow\{r+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which is the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by the map $a/b\rightarrow \{a+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}/\{b+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}$. So if $\{r_k+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ then there exist integers $a,b$ with $(a,b)=1$ such that $\{a+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}=\{r_k+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}\{b+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}=\{r_kb+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}$. If $p|b$ then $p\nmid a$ and this contradicts the equality $a+p\mathbb{Z}=r_1b+p\mathbb{Z}$. Then $p\nmid b$ and therefore $\{r_k+p^k\mathbb{Z}\}$ is the image of $a/b$ which is in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$